# Average of Squared $L^2$ Norm of Complex Valued Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's the problem statement: Let $f$ be holomorphic in $\{z ∈ ℂ: \|z\| < R\}$ for some $R>1$. Express the average of $\|f\|^2$ over the unit circle in terms of the coefficients of the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $0$.

Unless I'm doing something wrong, the average of $\|f\|^2 = f \overline f$ over the unit circle is $\|f\|^2(0) = f(0) \overline {f(0)}$, whence $f(0)$ is the only nonzero coefficient of the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $0$, centered at $0$: $f(0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(0 - 0)^n$; and there's nothing left to do.

Comment: How do you get the average? Do you integrate?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use Cauchy's integral formula. That theorem applies to holomorphic functions, which $f\overline f$ is not.

Comment: yes, I am using Cauchy's integral formula. I see, then how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is to determine
$${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{|z|=1}|f(z)|^2\,ds={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}|f(e^{i\theta})|^2\,d\theta$$
As $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $|z|<R,$ we have
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n,\quad a_n={f^{(n)}(0)\over n!}$$ and the series is uniformly and absolutely convergent for $|z|=1.$ So is the series
$$f(e^{i\theta})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{in\theta},\quad 0\le \theta<2\pi$$ By Parseval identity we get
$${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{|z|=1}|f(z)|^2\,ds=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2$$

Comment: Looks right, thanks.